# EF 4.1 Update 1 Code First + ASP.NET Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-membership, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I watched the “Creating immersive data experiences with Entity Framework “ video from this year’s BUILD conference and wanted to build out a simple application to test out the new features of EF. But, I’d also like to use the ASP.NET Membership Provider for managing users and roles within my app and I am struggling to find a clean way to include it in my code first approach. Do you guys have any recommendations, suggestions, or examples on how this could be done?

Comment: Don't do that. Membership Provider has its own API = use that API instead of wasting time by reinventing the wheel.

Comment: could you supply a link to the build video referenced?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the [MVC3-Boilerplate](https://github.com/crdeutsch/MVC3-Boilerplate) project on GitHub as it has a good example of creating a custom membership provider that is implemented using EF Code First.

Answer (score 0):

I found this NuGet package which has been very useful.

> Quickstart sample for using Altairis Web Security, Entity Framework and Unity in MVC 3. Super easy membership user/role integration. When using this quickstart, the users and role part of your project is completely setup. You can signup, login, edit roles for users etc.

http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/quickstart.mvc3.unity.ef.altairiswebsecurity

Answer (score 0):

[CodeFirstMembership](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/) may be what you are looking for.

Features:

- Based on GUID's
- Login either by entering Username or Email
- Username and Email are unique
- Uses nearly all features from SimpleMembershipProvider
- Code-First approach
- All membership fields can be renamed/changed/localized
- Easily extendable (add additional fields)
- VB.NET and C# versions available

Also, [ShoelaceMVC](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f94ba670-d5db-4b91-9a8f-6c53023c2c18) is a great MVC3 starter project that implements CodeFirstMemebership and comes with a nice layout thanks to [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).